# RoleManager.AddToRoleAsync not adding to AspNetUserRoles Table Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to seed users and roles to my DataContext. It is based on the following link;

[Seed EntityFramework Core 2.0](https://garywoodfine.com/how-to-seed-your-ef-core-database/)

I have the following in my startup.cs Configure method;

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
      var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
      await serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDataContext>().EnsureSeeded(roleManager);
}
```

Then in my EnsureSeeded method I run;

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, MyDataContext, int>(context);
await userStore.CreateAsync(user);
await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(user, "ADMIN");
await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(user, "MANAGER");
await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(user, "TRADER");
await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(user, "PUBLIC");
```

Now the User is added with the `CreateAsync(user)` ok, but the `AddToRoleAsync(user, "xxx");` is not adding to the roles in the database (AspNetUserRoles table)?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? As the Role does exist in the database? and the Normalized names should match?

Comment: Did u ever get to bototm of this ?